# TextView Wrap_Content height not working in some resolutions

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView with a text which only needs one line to be drawn. It has wrap_content for height.

In most of devices, the TextView is displayed correctly with a height that only represents one line. The problem is that in some devices, even with only one line, the text is being drawn with a doubled height, like if the text has a line break, but it doesn't have a line break.

Is when the device resolution fits the text width.

Here is how the text is being displayed with a height of two lines when it needs only one to be written:

[image]

How can that be avoided?

```
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/champion3Label"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:text="This is a test line wo jump"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/champion3Value"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/trophy3Image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />
```

I tried setting padding to 0dp and adding a margin instead, and the problem persists.

Comment: Try use `android:maxLines="1"` or `gravity` attribute

Comment: @AmanAnsari if i use maxLines="1" then, in devices with very low res, when 2 lines are necessary, i'm losing text, so i cant use that solution